# How do i call c#(dll) method using Perl?

Tags: c#, perl, dll

How do i call c#.net dll method in perl programming.

I have one dll that developed in c#....with name ClassLibrary1.dll, in this class i have one method called void add(int a,int b).

I need to calculate adding two number by passing argument to that dll using perl.

please help anyone.